# At the javascript, get value from C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Can I perform something like this?

**Situation**
I want to check the URL. if URL equal to http://sample.com, do this, otherwise, do that.

What I did:

In **Web.config** -

`<add key="ServerURLCloud" value="sample.com" />`

In **C#** -

```
public static string GetURL()
        {
            string[] url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerURLCloud"];
            return url;
        }
```

In **Javascript** -

```
if(varURL.indexOf('@ClassName.GetURL()') > 0){
   urlToCall = 'sub.sample.com';
}else{
   urlToCall = 'sub.not-sample.com';
}

$ajax(
url = urlToCall,
data = .........
....
)
```

I tested it, it is working **very well**. But, I want to know, will it be any problem if:

1. Internet connection slow

EDITED:

**My Question**

Is this practice (get Server side information at JavaScript) is good? Or bad?

Comment: Internet connection speed is irrelevant. The population of the variable has already happened when the page is returned (with everything else on it). It is not asynchronous. This is the standard way of populating a javascrtipt variable with server side information. Pleas ask specific questions, not open ended questions like "etc"

Comment: I put etc, because there is probably there is another scenario that I've miss looked. So, basically what you are saying that this way of implementation is fine? And, why votes down?

Comment: I think I need to edit my question, and I hope the vote down can be taken away.

Comment: I didn't vote down, but I did vote to close as your question is too broad. Same as the comment I made surrounding "etc". But yes the way you are doing this is fine. Don't worry about the down vote, they come with the territory. Phrase your questions better in the future and answer some questions well and you'll make up the odd downvote in no time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe this code sample can be altered slightly to make it a little easier to maintain.

You could create a variable in your layout which could contain ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerURLCloud"]

```
var siteSettings = {};
siteSettings.serverUrlCloud = '@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerURLCloud"]';
siteSettings.subSampleUrl = 'url';
siteSettings.subNotSampleUrl = '';
```

This site settings can hold anything useful as well (like base url etc)...

Also, try not to use magic strings in your code... instead, prefer to create variables/consts etc which hold these.

These changes wont impact the speed of your application but they will make it slightly easier to manage.

Also, the speed of the response from your ajax request is completely down to the executed code within that request, the length of the response and the internet connection speed... if the code is complex and doing a lot then it will naturally take longer. If the response is big, it will take longer to download. If the internet connection is slow, it will take longer to send the request and download the response.

Hope this helps

Comment: I would like to accept this as the answer because you give better implementation suggestion about 'create variables/consts' things. But first, are these variable/const better be included in the same page inside <scripts> or in separate JS file

Comment: I am a firm believer of seperating your concerns and splitting out js script into their own files especially when its logic for individual pages / controls etc. However, for the siteSettings object (mentioned above) i think they can be initialised in the _layout or master page. This is purely because they are global to your application and require values from web.config.